# Alternative to multiple constructors in angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

Angular 4 does not support mutliple constructors implementation, so I'm trying to find a cleaner way in to instantiate my object.

My model look like so

```
export class SrcFilter {

constructor(public fList?: Array<String>, public sList?: Array<String>, public tList?: Array<String>,
            public fList?: Array<String>, public fiList?: Array<String>, public sList?: Array<String>) {
 }
}
```

When I instantiate it, I'm forced to do like so:

```
allFilters: SrcFilter = new SrcFilter([], [], [], [], [], []);
```

Instatianting six lists is not pretty, I tried to have an second empty contructor to be able to do somting like

> new SrcFilter()

but angular conplains with multiple constructor implementations

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If there are no injection by Angular, you can create Factory methods to achive the easy way. Forexample:

```
export class SrcFilter {
  constructor(public aList?: Array<String>, public bList?: Array<String>, public cList?: Array<String>,
            public dList?: Array<String>, public eList?: Array<String>, public fList?: Array<String>) {
  }

  public static getDefault():SrcFilter {
    return new SrcFilter([],[],[],[],[],[]);
  }
}
```

then you could use to create new instances this line:

```
SrcFilter.getDefault();
```

Comment: Great idea, tkx